# Getting Deadlocks from simple atomic concurrent updates stmts. Any Ideas?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here's the message:

```
Transaction (Process ID 80) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

Here's the query:

```
update EDescriptionsCategories set CategoryId = Ids.CategoryId, AccessedDate = getdate() 
from EDescriptionsCategories 
join ( select * from (values (512528, 20870),(29596457, 20870)) as Ids(Id,CategoryId) ) as Ids on 
Ids.Id = EDescriptionsCategories.Id
```

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EDescriptionsCategories](
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AccessedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EDescriptionsCategories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Couple of those queries are running in parallel. Why the deadlock from single atomic update?

No other queries are running against this table. No indexes except primary key. However it is a big table 21 million rows.

Comment: Maybe HOLDLOCK or UPDLOCK will help? Maybe it's reading from the same table when you do from?

Comment: Is your table partitioned ? Do you have the deadlock information ? That might be a lock escalation deadlock

Comment: Table not partitioned. Here's a simple reproduceable example that you can run. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239143/this-simple-code-produces-deadlock-simple-example-program-included