# This simple code produces deadlock. Simple Example Program included

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

Code, notice the order of the values is different. So it alternates between locking rows:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();

            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
                list.Add( i );

            Parallel.ForEach( list, i =>
            {
                using( NamePressDataContext db = new NamePressDataContext() )
                {
                    db.ExecuteCommand( @"update EBayDescriptionsCategories set CategoryId = Ids.CategoryId from EBayDescriptionsCategories 
                        join (values (7276, 20870),(240, 20870)) as Ids(Id,CategoryId) on Ids.Id = EBayDescriptionsCategories.Id" );

                    db.ExecuteCommand( @"update EBayDescriptionsCategories set CategoryId = Ids.CategoryId from EBayDescriptionsCategories 
                        join (values (240, 20870),(7276, 20870)) as Ids(Id,CategoryId) on Ids.Id = EBayDescriptionsCategories.Id" );
                }

            } ); 
        }
```

Table def:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EDescriptionsCategories](
    [CategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EDescriptionsCategories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Exception:

```
Transaction (Process ID 80) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

The code works only with WITH (TABLOCK) hint. Is it possible not to lock the whole table just to update just those 2 rows in parallel?

Comment: I tried setting with(HOLDLOCK) which is supposed to do the same thing. Nothing works except WITH (TABLOCK). What I think is happening is that is starts locking each row individually. Because they start at different rows it deadlocks. I wonder if it's possible to lock all the referenced rows before updating can begin.

Comment: well, you update those 2 rows in reverse order, so these updates lock each other. Do you need to run in parallel two queries that work on the same rows ?

Comment: This is an exercise right? You wouldn't deliberately attempt to update two rows in parallel in the same transaction in production would you?

Comment: Can you change values (7276, 20870),(240, 20870)) as Ids(Id,CategoryId) to select * from (values (512528, 20870),(29596457, 20870)) as Ids(Id,CategoryId) ORDER BY Id to ensure that the update is processed in the same order

Comment: I simplified the problem. In the real application it updates random set of rows which I have no control over from different threads. So I cant combine those 2 statements. Is it possible to exclusively lock rows which I'm going to update before updating them. That will solve my problem.

Comment: @SteveFord - The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @Dennis, sorry you are right, but you can do it if you use TOP 100 percent as in join (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM (values (240, 20870),(7276, 20870)) as Ids(Id,CategoryId) ORDER BY Id) AS Ids on Ids.Id = #EBayDescriptionsCategories.Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two statements acquire row locks in different order. That's a classic case for deadlocks. You can fix this by ensuring that the order of locks taken is always in some global order (for example, ordered by ID). You should probably coalesce the two `UPDATE` statements into one and sort the list of IDs on the client before sending it to SQL Server. For many typical `UPDATE` plans this actually works fine (not guaranteed, though).

Or, you add retry logic in case you detect a deadlock (`SqlException.Number == 1205`). This is more elegant because it requires no deeper code changes. But deadlocks have performance implications so only do this for low deadlock rates.

If your parallel processing generates lots of updates, you could `INSERT` all those updates into a temp table (which can be done concurrently) and when you are done you execute one big `UPDATE` that copies all the individual update records to the main table. You just change the join source in your sample queries.

Comment: I simplified the problem. In the real application it updates random set of rows which I have no control over from different threads. So I cant combine those 2 statements. Is it possible to exclusively lock rows which I'm going to update before updating them. That will solve my problem.

Comment: @Dennis U-locks and X-locks behave the same way in this exact case. They block each other. So X-locks won't change anything. The problem is the order in which they are taken. If you want an easy fix do the retries or the insert table that I proposed. Both are totally safe.

Comment: I like your idea about ordering by Id. I think that should work. Because I'm building the ids myself and not from some ordered index. It's going to keep the U locks for each row until I commit. Right?

Comment: Yes, the U-locks must stay in place to support rollbacks. If you order the IDs the problem is gone. Btw, with table-valued parameters you can send an arbitrary amount of data at once.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm scared of table valued stuff because table valued return values from functions are super super slow. And in this case I don't have that many ids to pass. But I'll take a look at it. Moral of the story from here is to always pass the stuff in the same order when updating. Good to know!

Comment: A final comment regarding TVPs: for input params sent from ADO.NET they use an optimized code path and have special TDS support. Speed is comarable to SqlBulkCopy although a little slower. IOW 100k rows per sec plus.

Comment: Good to know. Do you think it will be faster for query sizes less than 65KB. Any limit on number of rows in TVPs?

Comment: As I can tell from the query plans the rows are streamed to a temp table. There is no inherent limit to the number of rows. I don't know how cardinality estimation works, though. You can also try to SqlBulkCopy all rows at once (really no limit) into a manually created temp table. I cannot think of anything faster. SqlBulkCopy can take an IEnumerable as input so you can use PLINQ to generate the inserts and they will be streamed with constant memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

> Code, notice the order of the values is different. So it alternates between locking rows

No, it doesn't alternate. It acquires the locks in two different order. Deadlock is **guaranteed**.

> Is it possible not to ... update just those 2 rows in parallel?

Not like that it isn't. What you're asking for is the definition of a deadlock. Something gotta give. The solution must come from your business logic, there should be no attempts to process the same set of IDs from distinct transactions.  What that means, is entire business specific. IF you cannot achieve that, then basically you are just begging for deadlocks. There are some things you can do, but none is bulletproof and all come at great cost. The problem is higher up the chain.

Comment: I simplified the problem. In the real application it updates random set of rows which I have no control over from different threads. So I cant combine those 2 statements. Is it possible to exclusively lock rows which I'm going to update before updating them. That will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with other answers as regards to the locking.

The more pressing question is what are you hoping to gain from this? There's only one cable those commands are travelling down.

You are probably making the overall performance worse by doing this. Far better to do your *computation* in parallel but serialize (and possibly batch) your updates.

Comment: I simplified the problem. In the real application it updates random set of rows which I have no control over from different threads. So I cant combine those 2 statements. Is it possible to exclusively lock rows which I'm going to update before updating them. That will solve my problem.

Comment: I think you'll still get deadlocks unless you rewrite your query to obtain locks in consistent order. It still does sound like the real application would benefit from centralizing and serializing updates if collisions are highly likely. It would probably improve throughput and give a more consistent latency.